# How to handle embedded separator in one or more fields using fread in R?

Tags: r, data.table, fread

I am using **fread** function for importing ".dat" file [file size 3.5 GB]. The issue with the file is some fields have embedded separator[I got to know as the same file is being used for loading via SSIS ETL tool] in it.

```
data <- fread("xyz.dat", sep = '|', encoding = "UTF-8",showProgress = T, select = ord_shp_col, fill = TRUE, sep2 = "|")
```

Tried sep2 argument to handle as per the R document and even tried with only limited column, so that such columns could be skipped.
However, ending with same error again n again.

> Read 0.0% of 1712440 rowsError in fread("xyz.dat", sep = "|", encoding
>   = "UTF-8",  :    Expecting 118 cols, but line 2143 contains text after processing all cols. Try again with fill=TRUE. Another reason could be
>   that fread's logic in distinguishing one or more fields having
>   embedded sep='|' and/or (unescaped) '\n' characters within unbalanced
>   unescaped quotes has failed. If quote='' doesn't help, please file an
>   issue to figure out if the logic could be improved.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @MrFlick I understand your concern, but the issue is with data load itself. After seeing the ways of reproducible example, I don't think I can help here as data is confidential. Could you please advise some ways to handle such scenario?? However I am trying hard if I could share some sample data.